# I am just curious to know why the following code does not give segmentation fault while executing

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function to print elements of a doubly linked list. I pass the head of the list to the function and use another variable inside the function. Without assigning the inside variable to the passed variable, I am able to access the list elements. [Note - AddtoHead function is not shown], Now added for clarity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};
void AddtoHead(struct Node **head_ptr, int data) {
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ptr);
    new_node->prev = NULL;

    if ((*head_ptr) != NULL)
        (*head_ptr)->prev = new_node;
    (*head_ptr) = new_node;
    return;
}
void PrintFList(struct Node *node) {
    struct Node* last;
    printf("\nWalking FAKE List : \n");
    printf("%d-> \n\n", last->data);
    last = last->next;
    printf("%d-> \n\n", last->data);    
    return;
}
/* Let's another function to see if it exhibits the same behaviour. A fun Mull to multiply two nos which would be passed as argument */
int Mull(int a, int b) {
    int c, d;
    printf("\n\n%d  %d\n", c, d);
    return c*d;
}

int main()
{
    // Start with the empty list 
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    int i;
    // Insert through a for loop
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        AddtoHead(&head, i+10);

    PrintFList(head);

    // Mull() function does not show the same behaviour 
    printf("\n\nMultiplication of a and b: %d \n\n", Mull(i, i+1));
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the following:

```
Walking FAKE List :
14->
13->
```

Whereas I was expecting a segmentation fault because last is not assigned

Comment: Undefined behavior can cause anything to happen, there's no requirement to detect the error and cause a fault.

Comment: By accident the uninitialized value of the variable contains the function argument.

Comment: Is there a scope of an accident in compiler ?? Just thinking... :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I'm just saying that it's using a register for `last`, and that register happens to be the same register that's used to pass the function argument.

Comment: An uninitialized pointer can contain anything. Sometimes it contains the address of memory that isn't assigned to the process, and you get a seg fault. Other times it contains the address of allocated memory, and you don't.

Comment: @Barmar To experiment your point, I just wrote a quick function to multiply two nos.  int Mull(int a, int b) {
    int c, d;
    printf("\n\n%d  %d\n", c, d);
    return c*d;
}
and then call it from main() like this -  printf("\n\nMultiplication of a and b: %d \n\n", Mull(i, i+1)); It prints some garbage value, meaning variable c,d is not taking the value of function argument a,b. So it looks like, "uninitialized value of the variable contains the function argument" not always the case. Any thoughts...

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Now I added AddtoHead() function. Yes it has pointer-to-pointer for head node.

Comment: After your edit I converted my previous comment into an answer.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I got your point. So I made some changes, like AddtoHead() first argument is a int variable and 2nd one is node poniter that did not change the behaviour. Looks like order of the function argument does not matter. To proof your point, I wrote a test function Mull(int a, int b) to multiply a and b. Then call this function before PrintFList() function. Then BOOM - got segmentation fault .. which I was expecting from the PrintList() function. I will add that portion of code as answer please review and comment. Looks like calling order also matter.

Comment: Of course calling order matters. I wasn't actually sure about the relevance of the returned value (because whenever possible it is placed in CPU registers) but any other call that changes the stack after AddToHead writing anything else in the stack will make `last` point to an invalid address leading to segmentation fault. (I  just edited my answer with an example reproducing a segfault).

Comment: Does not all local variables get allocated during compile time?? If it does, then calling order should not matter. Is not that correct ?

Comment: What I understood is, when PrintFList() function is called just after AddToHead() function, it is accessing the the dead variable data from AddToHead() function. AddToHead() already exited. So, it is able to print the list element. But when Mull() is called before PrintFList() function, at exit of Mull() function, two dead integer variable is in the stack and not a structure pointer which causes segmentation fault. But I may be wrong.

Comment: C doesn't do run-time error checking. Instead, the compiler attempts to detect common coding errors at compile time. So the correct answer to this question is compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, i.e. learn to use the tools correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behavior. It means that everything can happen depending on a lot of scenarios that might occur at runtime.

The value of `last` local variable of `PrintFList()` function is stored in the process stack. Since it has never been initialized, it contains any value was previosly written there before the call.

It happens that the previous call from main was `AddtoHead(14)`, and since it has a *signature* compatible to the one of `PrintFList` (meaning that both return `void` and have a single pointer parameter, so their calls will consume the stack in an identical way), its first local variable  (`node`) occupies **exactly** the same location that later will be occupied by `last`.

And what is the value of `node`? Well, it is the valid address of the last inserted node, and that's why no segmentation fault occurs, and the print starts exactly from the last inserted node (`"-> 14"`).

**How to obtain a segmentation fault**
Of course this apparently correct behavior is just luck: any further call before `PrintFList()` will likely overwrite that location of the stack, and a segmentation fault will occur.

In order to *obtain* the segfault you expected since the very first attempt you just have to place between `AddtoHead(14)` and `PrintFList()` a call to any function with some local variables in it. A simple example is... **`printf()`** (it for sure has a `va_list` local variable to parse its variadic arguments):

```
int main()
{
    // Start with the empty list 
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    int i;
    // Insert through a for loop
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        AddtoHead(&head, i+10);
        
    printf("hello %d times!\n", i); 

    PrintFList(head); // --> Segmentation fault!
}
```

Comment: I tried it out with printf("hello!\n"); It did not give seg fault. I got some wrong elements printed... hello!

Walking FAKE List :
14->

13->

Comment: Yea,may depend upon machine to machine. I am using Ubuntu with GCC 9. If I use the exact printf statement you showed, I get following output -  hello!


Walking FAKE List :
1->

1970220641->
But not seg fault in my system, Seems, it is un-predictable.

Comment: @NiranjanDas That's why it is called _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: Yes that's right. Even Barmar said the same thing, the very first comment to the post. I was just curious what was happening inside and why it was happening and how to get the desired result - "seg fault"

Comment: @NiranjanDas as I wrote in my answer, mess up enough with the stack (even though, according to your questions, you are not much familiar with what happens when code is executed) and you'll get a segfault. What I get with a single printf you can get with another function declaring enough local variables in a function and calling it before PrintFList

Comment: @NiranjanDas I edited my how-to-segfault example. I realized that some compilers can optimize printf with no formats to `puts`. Try the modified `printf`

Comment: I did modify printf() to as you stated like this way,  printf("hello %d time! \n",i); I am still getting this output and no seg fault: hello 5 time!


Walking FAKE List :
14->

13->

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults are caused when your program attempts to access memory that is not mapped in your virtual address space or that is mapped but not with permission for the type of access you attempted.

When an object is not initialized, the compiler is permitted to use any value for it. Your program might take a value from some processor register (such a register that the processor would have used for `last` if you had initialized it). That register might have the address of someplace in virtual memory where your program does have data, so it is mapped in your virtual address space and you can access it. This is not unlikely because your program has been using processor registers for various things, such as calculations or accessing memory, so sometimes they have valid memory addresses in them.

When this happens, your program accesses the memory and no segmentation fault occurs.

It is also not unlikely that the register would have had something other than a valid address in it, such as the result of calculating some expression or some values from intermediate parts of expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from Roberto Caboni, I have done some testing with the code to proof his point. I have added a small function Mull() which takes two integer and returns a*b Then I call this function before PrintFList() function, which gives segmentation fault.

```
int Mull(int a, int b) {
    printf("\n\na is: %d                b is: %d\n", a, b);
    return a*b;
}
```

Then, call it from main() in the following order, (If PrintFList call first, issue remains)

```
printf("Multiplication of a and b - (1st Mull call): %d ", Mull(i, i+1));
PrintFList(head);
```

which gives the following output:

```
a is: 5            b is : 6
Multiplication of a and b - (1st Mull call): 30

Walking FAKE List :
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now this, brings another question - Does not all local variables get allocated at compile time ?? Seems like function variable get allocated while they are being called. Otherwise, I am not able to explain why this works with Mull() function.

Comment: Local variables are placed in the stack at runtime. The state the stack will have when a function is called is something that compilers cannot predict.

Comment: When defining and declaring the function, I have already told the compiler what variables  are used in the function and their type. Then why the compiler not able to know while compiling the code ??? Just curious ! Then same thing should happen with main() as well ..should not it ?

Comment: @NiranjanDas The compiler *does* know that there's a problem with the code. You just need to enable the warnings, and fix the code. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @user3386109 Got that point ! But we are trying to understand at what time compiler allocates storage for functions other then main(). The reason we declare variables to tell the compiler to reserve storage according to its data type at compile time. Is not it ?

Comment: @NiranjanDas No. At compile time you translate your code into CPU _instructions_. When you execute these instructions, some of them will perform actions that will access memory. For example, declaring local variables in a function will lead to code writing and reading from specific memory locations. Those locations will be available again to the system as the function will return. Those specific locations will depend on the moment the function is called, so they are known only at run-time. At compile time you can have warnings because you access uninitialized a variable.

Comment: @NiranjanDas It may help to read about [call stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Though you need to be familiar with at least one processor architecture, and its associated assembly code, before any of this will make any sense.

Comment: I agree after compilation bunch of CPU instructions are created. When we execute, a.out those instructions are loaded into memory. But a.out also contains data segment, stack and heap memory. 1st instruction of the program is loaded to PC or Program Counter and then sequential execution begins.

Comment: a.out contains only the executable code and a section for both initialized and uninitialized global variables. The stack area is assigned by the OS to the process running your application, as well as a **segment** of the heap (that's why the OS, when a process accesses memory outside the segment, raises **segment**ation fault).

Answer (score 0):

I have already marked the answer to the question above. Just to drive home the point, let me give a simple example: Let's write two functions which multiply two integers passed as arguments to them. 1st Mul1() fun will have only 2 int var and 2nd Mul2() fun will have 4 int var - 2 as fun argument to Mul2() and 2 more as local variable to Mul2()

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Multiply fun with two integer variables
int Mul1(int a, int b) {
    printf("\n\na is: %d -- b is: %d \n", a, b);
    return a*b;
}
// Multiply fun with four integer variables
int Mul2(int a, int b) {
    int c, d;
    printf("\n\nc is: %d -- d is: %d\n", c, d);
    return c*d;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    printf("Multiplication of a and b - (1st Mull call): %d ", Mul1(i, i+1));
    printf("Multiplication of a and b - (2nd Mull call): %d ", Mul2(i, i+1));

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following output - from the output it can be seen that, variable c, d is occupying the location of var b, a from the previous call the Mul1() fun. Hence, though c, d is not assigned any value, it still prints 6 x 5 = 30 which is weird !

```
a is: 5 -- b is: 6
Multiplication of a and b - (1st Mul1 call): 30

c is: 6 -- d is: 5
Multiplication of a and b - (2nd Mul2 call): 30
```

So, I was interested to print the address of a,b,c,d in each Mul() function to see which space they are occupying. Issue becomes not reproducible the moment I modify/add printf() statement to print address. This is also as Roberto Caboni explained due to va_list argument in printf() -
Modify, Mul1() and Mul2() printf() as below and issue will disappear and (c*d) will print some garbage value which is expected behaviour.

```
printf("\n\na is: %d -- b is: %d  -- Address of a is: %p && Address of b is: %p\n", a, b, &a, &b);
printf("\n\nc is: %d -- d is: %d  -- Address of c is: %p && Address of d is: %p\n", c, d, &c, &d);
```

After modification to the printf() statements in both Mul1() and Mul2() function, out is shown below: From the address print, we can see that this time, all variables a,b,c,d are getting unique address starting from 0x84a0 to 0x84ac occupying 16 bytes in stack (4 bytes each for each integer)

```
a is: 5 -- b is: 6  -- Address of a is: 0x7ffd187084ac && Address of b is: 0x7ffd187084a8
Multiplication of a and b - (1st Mul1 call): 30

c is: -1403531320 -- d is: 32522  -- Address of c is: 0x7ffd187084a0 && Address of d is: 0x7ffd187084a4
Multiplication of a and b - (2nd Mul2 call): 1266832848
```

Comment: A point to be noted is, is there a way for compiler to prevent such errors ?? One possibility, wipe out the values on function exits though it may be expensive and could slow down the execution time.